# By ourselves puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the 4-word phrase I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> **ISLAND NATIONS OF EUROPE**

The first diagram, comprising a set of seven boxes...

> ...shows the initial letters of the seven continents, roughly arranged in their relative geographical positions. The 'E' in a red circle represents the continent of **EUROPE**.

The image showing numbers on a watery background...

> ...represents the relative positions of the five European island nations on a map, where the numbers are the letter counts of the country names in English - from top to bottom:
>
>  7 alone = Iceland;
>  7 and 13 paired = Ireland and United Kingdom (which border each other in real life);
>  5 = Malta;
>  6 = Cyprus.
>
>  [image: Map of Europe]
>
>  (The use of an image of water for the background confirms this...)

Putting these together, the final answer requires the word from part 1 to be inserted where the red ring is, and the theme from part 2 to be inserted where the white-filled circle is. Doing so helps us populate the missing 7-letter word beginning with 'N' too...

> **ISLAND NATIONS OF EUROPE**. And, of course, the connotations of being 'an island' corresponds with the use of 'by ourselves' in the title.

Comment: That's the phrase! Very fast too. Great job!

Comment: @Prim3numbah For some reason, this one just clicked immediately for me (and I happened to see it very soon after posting)!